# Replace contents in a variable using powershell

Tags: powershell, macros

So I have some code saved in a variable eg; $Macro in a powershell script.
I need to replace the entire lines starting from **Dim stm** till **Set al** and save the output back in the variable $Macro.

```
entry_class = "enumerate.now"

Dim stm As Object, fmt As Object, al As Object
Set stm = CreateObject("System.IO.MemoryStream")
Set fmt = CreateObject("System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter")
Set al = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

Dim dec
dec = decodeHex(serialized_obj)
```

Can someone provide any pointers how would I do it ?
I tried using the below, but it did not work

```
$macro = $macro -replace 'Dim stm As Object, fmt As Object, al As Object',' replaced code'
$macro = $macro -replace 'Set stm = CreateObject("System.IO.MemoryStream")',' replaced code'
```

Answer (score 0):

Powershell does not understand newline by default and parentheses and commas should be escaped using back tick and you don't need regex in replacing so you have to do this:

```
$macro = 'entry_class = "enumerate.now" Dim stm As Object`, fmt As Object`, al As Object`nSet stm = CreateObject`("System.IO.MemoryStream"`)`nSet fmt = CreateObject`("System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter"`)`nSet al = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")`nDim dec`ndec = decodeHex`(serialized_obj`)'
$macro = $macro.replace("Dim stm As Object`, fmt As Object`, al As Object'", '"replaced code")
$macro = $macro.replace('Set stm = CreateObject`("System.IO.MemoryStream"`)',' replaced code')
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for it.. that helped, I instead replaced the starting of each line with a comment ('), my next step is to add the following data [snippet] to the same variable at a specific line. Any pointers here ?                                                                                           
                                                                                                                          
 manifest = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-16"" standalone=""yes""?><assembly xmlns=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"" manifestVersion=""1.0"">

Comment: But ' is not a commenting method in powershell. It is the commenting method in VBScript. In powershell # is used instead. And if it worked accept the answer by clicking the grey tick mark located in the answer.